# How to serve robots.txt in a --no-brunch Phoenix API-only app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, robots.txt

I have a Phoenix JSON API only application that was created with `--no-brunch` and serves no static content.

I'm seeing errors from bots trying to crawl my `robots.txt`, which is nonexistent, and renders a `500.json-api` view, causing an exception when `Phoenix.Template.HTML.encode_to_iodata!` tries to encode JSON.

Is there a better way to serve `robots.txt` without doing static asset compilation so I can avoid these errors, and ideally disallow crawling of my API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following to your `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex` file:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(robots.txt)
```

You'll need to change the `my_app` part of course.

If you're deploying to Heroku you should either:

- Include the Phoenix static buildpack if you're using brunch and compiling other assets. Documentation for deploying to Heroku with notes about the static buildpack can be found here: https://phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku
- If using `--no-brunch`, then uncomment `.gitignore` which is ignoring `/priv/static` in favor of `/web/static`.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense, though my particular case was a little more complex.

My `Endpoint` does indeed `plug Plug.Static`, but I'm deploying to Heroku and therefore needed to include Phoenix static buildpack and uncomment my `.gitignore` which was ignoring `/priv/static` in favor of `/web/static`.

Documentation for others can be found here: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku

Comment: I edited your answer with my notes above. Feel free to revert if you're not happy with them.

Comment: Looks good to me! I didn't know about the buildpack problem, actually. Good to know.